# Spring Boot MVC for the same endpoint sending two different responses (with a little difference)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a not-a-common requirement where I am two different type of consumers for my microservices. One type of consumer is okay with the type-of-response that I am sending them, whereas the other consumer has a requirement where we have to follow their structure (its pretty strict on this).

Lets say I have a `StudentController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {
    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public Student getStudent(@PathVariable String name) {
        return Student.builder()
                .name(name)
                .subjects(List.of("Maths", "English"))
                .dateJoined(LocalDate.now().toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is alright as one my consumer is accepting my response, where my response looks like this:

{"name":"smit","subjects":["Maths","English"],"dateJoined":"2020-04-26"}

However, the another consumer says that you should sending me the SAME object in a another from something like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/wrapper")
public class WrapperController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentController studentController;
    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public WrapperResponse getStudent(@PathVariable String name){
        return WrapperResponse.builder()
                .responseTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.now().toString())
                .data(studentController.getStudent(name))
                .build();
    }
}
```

The below is the output of the above controller.

{"data":{"name":"smit","subjects":["Maths","English"],"dateJoined":"2020-04-26"},"responseTimeStamp":"2020-04-26T01:11:32.986"}

Summary: WrapperController is internally calling StudentController and then wrapping the response in the custom "WrapperResponse" class and then sending that as a response.

Problem: As of now it does solve the problem but I have many such controllers and in my different microservices. So I do not want to rewrite the "WrapperController" for each controller and each microservice.

Comment: How do you differentiate two clients if they are using the same endpoints?

Comment: @caco3 They are on different mappings

Comment: Correct @123 Wrapper is an extention to Student. I do not have restriction on the end-point (for the wrapper). I can have "/wrapper/student/{name}" and "/student/{name}" if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much opinion-based, but here's how I would refactor this:

- Create a Student service (StudentService) that creates the Student,
  rather than doing that in the Controller.
- Push the code for building a WrapperResponse into the WrapperResponse class itself - either as a static 'factory' method, or as constructor. Have the method take a Student as a parameter.
- For each different kind of 'Wrapper' object that you want to supply, have your controller method call the StudentService to get the base Student class, and then construct the Wrapper object by passing the Student to the factory method or constructor of the Wrapper object.

So, your WrapperController might end up looking like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/wrapper")
public class WrapperController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public WrapperResponse getStudent(@PathVariable String name){
        return new WrapperResponse(studentService.getStudent(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have considered doing the same as well. However I was looking for a generic soln where I can apply this logic to any number of controllers or equivalent handler I have. I do not wish to repeat the wrapper methods for every controller method.

Comment: I was hoping to creating of annotation that could enable such kind of transformation.